# How to make QListView emit a custom SIGNAL and call a custom SLOT to handle it?

Tags: qt, qt-signals

How can I make a `QListView` emit a custom `SIGNAL` called `onListViewItemSelectionChanged` whenever its item selection has been changed either by clicking or by using the up and down arrow keys, so that I could assign a custom `SLOT` called `changeLineEditText` to handle the `SIGNAL`?

Answer (score 0):

You can take `selectionModel` of the list view and connect your slot to its `currentChanged` signal :

```
connect(listView->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(​currentChanged(const QModelIndex &,const QModelIndex &)),
        this,SLOT(changeLineEditText(const QModelIndex &,const QModelIndex &)));
```

Here the first argument is the current selected index and the second one is the previous index.